# jQuery - how to check if a dynamically created audio element is paused

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I've created an audio element. How do I check if the element is paused?

```
var $audio = $("<audio></audio>").attr({
    'src':'kassets/sound/intro.mp3',
    'autoplay':'autoplay'
});

var $audiocontrol = $('<i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
$audiocontrol.on("click", function(e){
    if($audio.paused == false){
        $audio.trigger("pause");
    }else{
        $audio.trigger("play");
    }
});

var $flyer = $('<div class="style_intro"></div>');

$( "body" ).append( $audio, $audiocontrol, $flyer );
```

Comment: `if($audio[0].paused == false)`?! You want to check property of DOM node, not of jq object

Comment: @A.Wolff ya, that worked, thanks